# DB2 - All SQL statements only return strings and always result in this error: VARIABLE definition does not match the column type associated with it

Tags: db2, cobol

As the title says, every time I try and create int or decimal field pic clauses, I get that syntax error. I checked my tables in my DB2 and only 2 fields are actually Char fields. All the others are numeric. What is weird is that I can literally define a string version with the proper length of the PIC clause and it accepts it. I just would like to know why I cant use Int/Dec values when my database clearly stores them as so. Thanks in advance.

Here is a img of my DB2 table structure.
[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46ZBk.png)

This shows that the values im retrieving are clearly int/decimal etc. Here in my application, it somehow thinks otherwise. ProdPrice should work but it doesnt. Its column matches my table but will only be error-free if I make it a PIC X(10). Any solutions?

```
01 PRODID   PIC  X(10) .
01 SUPPID   PIC  X(10) .
01 PRODNAME.
       49 NAME-LENG PIC S9(4) COMP-4.
       49 NAME-VAL PIC X(30).
01 PRODPRICE    PIC S9(8)V9(2).
01 PRODDESC.
       49 DESC-LENG PIC S9(4) COMP-4.
       49 DESC-VAL PIC X(200).
```

Here is my SQL..

```
EXEC SQL
            SELECT PROD_NAME, PROD_DESCRIPTION, PROD_PRICE, 
            SUPP_ID
            INTO :PRODNAME, :PRODDESC, :PRODPRICE, :SUPPID
            FROM  PRODUCT
            WHERE PROD_ID = :PRODID
END-EXEC.
```

Comment: What do you get if you run a DCLGEN command for your table?

Comment: What do you get when replacing `COMP-4` (`BINARY`) with `COMP-3` (`PACKED-DECIMAL`), at least for your decimal `PRODPRICE`?

Comment: The question would be much more useful if you replace the image with the text...

Comment: For `COMP-4` [the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-using-binary-items-in-sql) says "If [...] `TRUNC(OPT)` or `TRUNC(STD)` is in effect [...]  the data might not be valid because of the decimal truncation rules" - what `TRUNC` option _is_ used?

Comment: The table structure shows the `INT` fields to be of length 4 bytes. The COBOL fields defined as  `S9(4) COMP-4` are two bytes. Try `PIC S9(9) COMP-4?`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

I simply changed COMP-4 to COMP-3. If there is still a problem, make sure to have an 'S' defined in the numeric fields PIC clause.

```
Example:
01 SUPPID       PIC  S9(6) COMP-3.          *int
01 PRODPRICE    PIC  S9(8)V9(2) COMP-3.     *decimal
01 CLIENTID     PIC  X(5).                  *string
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. `COMP-3` is packed decimal, whereas `COMP-4` is binary integer. The table definition shows the columns are the latter. If DB2 indeed does a type conversion from `INT` to `DECIMAL PACKED` when retriveing the data, the field is still too small. A signed `INT` field may hold numbers as large as 2'147'483'648, i.e. 10 digits. So, the field should be defined as `PIC s9(10) COMP-3`.